# Is this method overloading in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, overloading

In the below code , can I say `class B` has overloaded `add` method ?

```
class A
{
   public void add()
     {
           //some code
     }

}
class B extends A
{
    public void add(int a)
     {
            // some code
     }

}
```

Comment: Yes, you can safely say that.

Answer (score 3):

*Nods*

Yes, that's an example of method overloading. An example of method overriding would be,

```
class B extends A{
    @Override
    public void add(){
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the perspective of the API exposed by `B`, an `add` method already exists, even if provided by the superclass. Since you provide another `add` method with different arguments, this is overloading. To have provided the same signature would have been overriding.

Comment: Wouldn't that rather be `hiding` than overriding? Overriding is something that must be done explicitly.

Comment: Ok. I've then just learned another way in which C# differs from java then. :-)

Comment: @Klaus: Java considers hiding to differ from overriding in the sense that the method called depends on the *declared* type, not the actual object instance. Hiding applies to static methods, overriding to non-static ones. See [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html). (I removed my previous comments to improve readability)

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is method overloading.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can say that class `B` has overloaded the method `add()`. As `public void add()` is already present in class B, due to inheritance. Creating a method with same name, but a different signature (ie. the number, type, and order of the parameters) is overloading.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Consider this more straightforward example of overloading:

```
class A
{
   public void add()
     {
           //some code
     }

   public void add(int a)
     {
           //this method is overloading add() from within its own class
     }

}
```

Now, since B, in your example code extends A, it inherits add() and so it's safe to say that even though add() is not explicitly defined in B, the method is available, and so defining add(int a) may be considered overloading of add()